# Can't bind result of <select> to bool

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

My razor component:

```
<label for="Title">Leasing?</label>
<select class="form-control" @bind="IsLeasing">
    <option value="" selected >Please choose...</option>
    <option value="True">Yes</option>
    <option value="False">No</option>
</select>

code {
    private bool isLeasing { get; set; }
}
```

The problem I have with this code is that, as soon as I pick an option, the rendered select box instantly switches back to the initial option. I'm running that code in a BlazoredModal, but I don't think that this matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bind property won't work here due to difference in datatype. What you are trying to bind if of type bool and `<select>` works on string. You can add a `onchange` handler to perform a change and then parse the result and  assign it to `IsLeasing`

**Razor Markup**

```
<select class="form-control" @onchange="(e) => OnLeasingChanged(e.Value)">
    <option value="" selected >Please choose...</option>
    <option value="True">Yes</option>
    <option value="False">No</option>
</select>
```

**Code**

```
private bool? IsLeasing { get; set; }

void OnLeasingChanged(object args)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(args.ToString()))
    {
        IsLeasing = null;    
        return;
    }
        
    bool.TryParse(args.ToString(),out var result);        
    IsLeasing = result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A Blazor/Razor `<select>` always works with type `string`. Because of that you need to convert the values back and forth, as in this example:

```
@code {
    private bool IsLeasing
    {
        get => IsLeasingString == "True";
        set => IsLeasingString = value.ToString();
    }
    private string IsLeasingString { get; set; }
}

<label for="Title">Leasing: @IsLeasing</label>
<select class="form-control" @bind="IsLeasingString">
    <option value="" selected>Please choose...</option>
    <option value="True">Yes</option>
    <option value="False">No</option>
</select>
```

---

PS: the @bind parameter is *case sensitive*, and as a result the code from your question doesn't compile as-is. Please be as exact as possible, and try to avoid using improvised code...